# How to keep permanent connection to DB from Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, model-view-controller

**Summary: I can't keep database connection active in Spring MVC, that's why all queries execute slowly (first connect, than execute). Below I explain it in details.**

I go on studying java. I made some [simple websocket chat](https://github.com/freshnoon/testweb3) using servlets and JSP. I'll call it Project#1. Now I'm reworking it to the more modern technology of Spring MVC using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. The current result is [here](https://github.com/freshnoon/SpringBootThymeleaf), i'll call it Project#2.

Project#2 now runs the same functions as Project#1 except some details. But there's a one big problem.

As I switch between contacts, my app sends ajax query to the server and gets message history. And in Project#2 it happens sloooooowly. Much more slowly than in Project#1.

I believe that it's because in Project#1 MySQL connection stores manually in the Httprequest attribute. It's being done by servlet filter like this:

```
Connection conn = null;
        try {
            // Create a Connection.
            conn = ConnectionUtils.getConnection();
            // Set outo commit to false.
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            // Store Connection object in attribute of request.
            MyUtils.storeConnection(request, conn);

            // Allow request to go forward
            // (Go to the next filter or target)
            chain.doFilter(request, response);

            // Invoke the commit() method to complete the transaction with the DB.
            conn.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ConnectionUtils.rollbackQuietly(conn);
            throw new ServletException();
        } finally {
            ConnectionUtils.closeQuietly(conn);
        }
```

As I need to get something from DB I use existing connection like this:

```
Connection conn = MyUtils.getStoredConnection(request);
ArrayList<UserAccount> userList = new ArrayList();
    try {
        userList = DBUtils.userList(conn, loginedUser.getUserName());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        errorString = e.getMessage();
    }
```

But, in Spring MVC there's another technology for DB connection. DAO classes and so on. My application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://freshnoon.beget.tech/freshnoon_chat
spring.datasource.username=freshnoon_chat
spring.datasource.password=hgy78fdXVb0
```

For unknown reason that's not enough (I get an error of missing DataSource bean). So I added this bean to WebConfig.java:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://freshnoon.beget.tech/freshnoon_chat?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
    dataSource.setUsername("freshnoon_chat");
    dataSource.setPassword("hgy78fdXVb0");

    return dataSource;
}
```

DB queries are now handled by `DatabaseAccess extends JdbcDaoSupport`:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DatabaseAccess extends JdbcDaoSupport {

@Autowired 
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public DatabaseAccess(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.setDataSource(dataSource);
}
```

For example, a method for getting history:

```
public List<Message> getHistory(String sender, String reciever) throws SQLException {

    String sql = "Select * from MESSAGES m where m.Sender = ? and m.Reciever = ? or m.Sender = ? and m.Reciever = ?";
    Object[] args = new Object[] { sender, reciever, reciever, sender };
    MessageMapper mapper = new MessageMapper();

    try {
        List<Message> history = this.getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, args, mapper);
        return history;
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As I noticed, second technology works too slow. I recorded 2 videos to represent:

- [Project#1 video (fast one)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KSjzp5-DSdEcRD57ttRlTEvJz2Vu8A0V)
- [Project#2 video (slow one)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1l_nbCZTn_kadDB7yAwfn6olclz7D3RP5)

Thank you for reading such big text! Please give an advice how to keep connection to DB in Project#2 (Spring MVC).

Comment: It's time for you to learn about the wonderful world of **connection pooling** (if you have a recent Spring Boot project, you get good defaults set up, but your Project #2 is misconfigured). The approach used in Project #1 is not something you'd use for "real" projects, with long lasting connections like that.

Comment: Ditch your bean, and solve the error you have. Your bean is a `DriverManager` based solution which doesn't pool connections but opens one when needed. So you either are using properties from Spring Boot without actually using Spring Boot, or have disabled parts of the auto-configuration when using Spring Boot, or aren't using Spring Boot properly (I suspect either option 2 or 3).

Comment: @Kayaman, why is Project #2 misconfigured? What is it's problem?

Comment: I recommend the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/). It's well written, and most of all, correct. Datasource configuration is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-data-access).

Comment: @Kayaman, I already thought so. Thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed connection pool. Application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://freshnoon.beget.tech/freshnoon_chat?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=freshnoon_chat
spring.datasource.password=hgy78fdXVb0
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=15
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=15
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=8
spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=true
```

Some required dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I got it from this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-tomcat-connection-pool).

Maybe it's not the best way for my app. Maybe I made some mistakes implementing it. But I already see the difference, messages load much faster. Thanks for comments, going on studying ;)